# Copy from documentation and mentioning source not enough

Tags: support, deleted-answers

[My answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoASF.png) to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933277/how-to-clear-nuget-package-cache-using-command-line) with 25 votes was deleted and reason was copy from Microsoft documentation.

A link was provided of source documentation for more and only the needed part was copied with small modification to meet question as was no need to rewrite it.

I cannot see my answer anymore and below was the reserved comment for it by moderator

[image]

Comment: If you link to the answer, or provide a screenshot, it would be easier to give you feedback.

Comment: @yivi this answer to be precise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54800684

Comment: @yivi I updated the question with needed link

Comment: Also I cannot see my answer anymore

Comment: There is one other intriguing question: That answer doesn't belong to you, or at least the answer seems to be disassociated. When did that happen?

Comment: I'm confused. There is an answer you deleted yourself 6 minutes ago. The answer deleted by a moderator was given by a now deleted user?

Comment: @rene the ansower I am asking for was deleted by anther user today, I just added a new one and delete it now

Comment: @Elastic You can always see your deleted posts if you have a link.

Comment: I'll copy over the comments I already left on the MSE post earlier: Yes, we don't like plagiarism, at all, seriously. If you don't attribute where you quote stuff from and make it appear you wrote it yourself, posts will be deleted, no matter how many votes/views it had. And someone even [tried to save it with an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54800684/revisions) which was rolled back

Comment: But you say "**my** answer"?

Comment: @yivi Its my answer and deleted a moderator

Comment: I think it is better to have Martijn sort this one out. Probably more going on then we can see.

Comment: If [this answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoASF.png) is the answer you are talking about, then it at least seems as if it wasn't written by you (or at least not with the account you use now).

Comment: @BDL yes this was my answer, why my account not appearing and it show anon?

Comment: the *anon* part is to remove the reputation from your account. Old answers with 6+ won't have reputation removed if they are deleted but this is a clear case of plagiarism so special action was needed to remove the reputation. (I remember flagging such answer and the same was done)

Comment: @TemaniAfif needed section was copied from documentation and source documentation was mentioned for more

Comment: which is a *Wholesale copy and paste from the linked page.* like commented. Did you write something on your own? All I can see is the same sentences from that link

Answer (score 15):

In general, providing a link to the source alone is not enough, especially not when the link text is "For more details". Copied content has to be marked explicitly in a blockquote and a proper attribution has to be given. Also note, that

This can, for example, be done in the following form

> As stated in the [Microsoft Documentation, Section XYZ](https://XYZ), the following code should help:
>
> > CODEBLOCK
>
> If that doesn't help, you can also try ABC.

Providing an answer that consists solely of a quote from one source is in general a bad idea. Every answer should contain at least some original content.

Also note, that a user tried to fix the problem with your question by marking it correctly as copied content, but you rolled the edit back which left not many other options than deleting the answer.

As stated by Temani Afif:

> Old answers with 6+ won't have reputation removed if they are deleted but this is a clear case of plagiarism so special action was needed to remove the reputation. (I remember flagging such answer and the same was done)

Comment: Moderate can update it or leave comment and I will update it with the blockquote

Comment: @ElasticCode: It was tried to update the answer but you rolled back the change. What did you expect to happen afterwards?

Comment: It wasn't updated with blockquote as you mentioned and no comment was provided to show that

Comment: [Revision with blockquote](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54800684/4). Edit description: "Properly [...] cited this content as originating from another document"

Comment: The edit comment was not clear for me but now its after your answer, Thanks

Comment: I updated my answers as you mentioned but the same moderate deleted it again!?

Comment: I can't emphasise this enough: Answers that are just *wholesale copies* are just copyright violations and just as much plagiarism. As per the [help center on referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing): **do  _not_ copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.**

Comment: @ElasticCode: It was still not your own, original work. Nothing in that post was written by you, a blockquote and link does not make it any less just a copy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters♦ it was not just copy try to check the documentation and my answer I add my own updates but inside the blockquote

Comment: @ElasticCode deepfake? You either quote the source (with attribution) or provide your own content. You don't *change* quote to fit your needs...